# nonetype error when comparting two float values

Tags: python

hi there i have this function to run a secant method from values and an equation that are taken from the user as input but when i go to run it the while loop wont run because  f_a f_b f_c are all none types and i cant use > to compare none types to floats. is there a fix for this ?

```
def SecantMethod(a, b, tolerance, function):
    a = float(a)
    b = float(b)
    tolerance = float(tolerance)
    function = str(function)
    iteration = 0
    f_a = 1.0
    f_b = 1.0
    f_c = 1.0
    while (f_a>tolerance or f_b>tolerance or f_c>tolerance):
        c=(a + b)/2
        f_a = solve(function, a)
        f_b = solve(function, b)
        f_c = solve(function, c)
        a=b
        b=c
        iteration+=1
    text="stopped at iteration = {}\n  a = {}\n  b = {}\n  c = {}\n f(a) = {}\n f(b) = {}\n f(c) = {}\n" 
    print(text.format(iteration, a, b, c, f_a, f_b, f_c))
```

also heres the solve function if its needed

```
def solve(function, n):
    e1=function.replace('x', 'n')
    eval(e1)
```

i want to to loop till f_a or the others are smaller than the tolerance

Comment: Why don't you post the full error message including the stack trace?

Comment: Anyway, your `solve` function **always** returns `None`, probably, that isn't what you meant to do

Comment: solve uses integer values, not str values, probably that's why they are returning None

Comment: `solve` should return a value, because you're re-assigning the values of `f_a`, `f_b`, and `f_c` to its return value. But since you did not return anything after the `eval`, the function returns `None`.

`solve` is not using the `n` parameter, just a fixed `"n"` string. 
Also, you should give an example of how the `SecantMethod` function is used.